# Send token in every WebSocket (or TCP) request

Tags: authentication, tcp, websocket

I'm developing a client-server application which uses **WebSocket**. I have implemented **token-based** authentication with JWT. Once my client has a valid token, a WebSocket **connection is opened indefinitely**.

Is it a good idea to **send the token within each request**? Is there any chance of anyone to hijack the connection?

My question actually applies to any TCP-based connection which requires authentication.

Comment: Authentication without encryption is, at best, questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any chance of anyone to hijack the connection? ... My question actually applies to any TCP-based connection which requires authentication.

Yes it is possible to hijack existing TCP connections or just be the man in the middle when you start a new one. The protection against this is not to send the authentication within each message because these could be simply replicated by the attacker. Instead use encryption, i.e. `wss://` in case of WebSockets or TLS, IPSec or similar in other cases. These protect against both active man in the middle attacks (hijacking) and passive sniffing.